# Facebook Login email + password not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook

I am using Facebook Login for a Firebase app. I used to be able to fill in email + password, but now I only see a button to authenticated with my Facebook app on my iPhone (in simulator it is working ok and asking email + password). Which will not work because my app is still in development.

[image]
[image: This is what I excpect. On simulator it goes as expected, on device not]

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Email & password are not what log you into *your* app. You only get asked for email & password, to log into your Facebook account first, when necessary.

If you are already in the Facebook app, that step is of course not required any more.

> Which will not work because my app is still in development.

That has nothing to do with it, your app login will still work for any user with a role in the app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the login procedure and how it works, but I need to have the option to fill in email + password, so I can login with my testing credentials. Now the only option I have is to login with the button in the image, which will bring me to my "real" Facebook account.

Comment: Then you will need to log out of your account that you are currently logged into Facebook with first. (You said you were using the Facebook app, but your screenshot appears to just show facebook.com accessed in a browser?)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately logging out does not work, tried it several times. Besides, logging out of the Facebook was not needed earlier, I just had a textfield for email and password...

Comment: Are you asking about username and password to login to Facebook itself then, or about logging in to an existing firebase account using this kind of credentials, _instead_ of performing the login via Facebook?

Comment: Updated my question. I use Facebook as login credential for a Firebase user account (Firestore, chat, etc.). For testing on a real device I need to login as well, but the only option I have is to login with my real FB account (image 1) instead of email+password, so I can use a FB testing account.